# Remove single quotes around string in excel

Tags: excel, substitution

In my excel I have the following text in a cell:

```
INSERT INTO `educations`(`education_id`, `school`, `specialization`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL,'NULL','software','2006-01-01 00:00:00','2006-01-01 00:00:00',@inserted_id);
```

I want to (programmatically) substitute all the 'NULL' and change them to NULL (without the quotes).

I tried using the substitute function but I cannot get it working.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(DU7;"''NULL''";"NULL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

`=SUBSTITUTE(DU7;"'NULL'";"NULL")`

Not sure why you were repeating the single quote marks.

Malcolm

Comment: I can't believe that actually did it.. I feel so stupid now! Thank you!

Comment: Use formula option when you post a formula

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

Single quote -

`=SUBSTITUTE(DU7;"'NULL'";"NULL")`

Substituting single quotes is easier, just like how you substitute other strings, But substituting double quotes has to be written similar to how you have did.

Double Quote-

`=SUBSTITUTE(DU7;"""NULL""";"NULL")`

Answer (score 1):

Use Find and Replace Function in Excel, Use this

Find What: 'NULL'

Replace With: NULL

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a solution but i wanted to do it programmatically !

Comment: @Dennis You can still do it that way and record a macro. Then Excel will write the VBA code for you.